# Android, Picasso - most of the images don't want to load (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, image, kotlin, picasso

I'm trying to build a RecyclerView filled with a card view items. For each item I need 2 small images that I load from URL. Everything works fine only if I load sample image from Picasso website (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg). Every other picture I try to load doesn't show up.

Here's my code; inside my RecyclerViewAdapter, inside the onBindViewHolder() function I'm calling:

```
fun loadImageInBackground(item : Footballer,  holder : ViewHolder){
    doAsync {
        var loadImage = Picasso.get().load(item.footballerImageUrl)
        var loadFlagImage = Picasso.get().load(item.flagImageUrl)
        uiThread {
            loadImage.into(holder?.footballerImage)
            loadFlagImage.into(holder?.flagImage)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Kotlin ANKO for "doAsync". 
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't need to `doAsync` for picasso. It is async insode itself

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Ok, I removed this part, but the issue is still there. 
Here are some images I tried to use:
1.https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bandsapp2.appspot.com/o/footballers%2FScreenshot%202018-10-20%20at%2013.23.45.png
2.https://ibb.co/dB5qmL

None of this works.

Comment: First link does not open. It actually does, but showes JSON instead of image. obviously Picasso won't load JSON. Second link showes not an image, but the web page. Picasso is obviously unable to load the web pages as well\

Answer (score 0):

I partly solved this. It seems like I was using wrong links, but I'm not sure where was the issue.

Now when I upload a picture to imgur.com and copy a direct link it works. But what's the rule for the links? Why the previous mentioned were not working? Can anybody guide me here?

Comment: The rule for the link is to address an image, so Picasso can process it. Any other type of content will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below methods its working for me.

build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Java Code :

```
Picasso.get().load("URL PATH").into(Image_view)
```